# Installing a different Linux software through Ubuntu without BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm new to Linux and I've wanted to get Kali Linux on a Laptop instead of a VM on my PC.

I managed to install Ubuntu then I felt like I didn't like it so I wanted to switch to Kali Linux because it suits my needs more, anyhow, how would I install a whole new Linux software using Ubuntu, I can't use the BIOS Boot manager because my Screen is broken so I have to use a monitor which also doesn't let me see the BIOS so I looked into Super boot manager but can't install it, any help?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  If you don't like Ubuntu I'd suggest its the DEsktop maybe that doesn't suit your needs; and installing another DEsktop may be the answer (eg. `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop` which would install the MATE desktop but it doesn't need to be MATE; it's my example).  Underneath Kali is a modified debian setup for pentesting with >98% of the same software. Ubuntu itself is a tailored debian too so I don't see much difference beyond 'setup' that you can change anyway.  For KALI Questions though you need to use elsewhere (eg. stackexchange linux & unix site)

Comment: Yes i get that, but my question is how do i install a new linux system through ubuntu, since like i said my laptop screen is broken so i can't view my bios boot menu.

Comment: If Ubuntu is running from a partition; that partition will be 'busy' so it cannot be installed there (format impossible which means a very different OS can't be done). You could however chroot to say a usb drive so you could umount the partition (or dump gui & do it all at tty), then dd the data across - which technically would be using Ubuntu to install another OS - but it'd be very specific to your hardware/machine.  Your machine sounds like a laptop so just hit the <fn><scr> keys to have external screen 'clone' the original (keys being whatever brand yours uses)